# Android terminology

Tags: android, dynamic, terminology

I have created a few apps with basic features with the help of tutorials.  But when I decided to explore the next level of features, I didn't know what the features were termed, and hence found it difficult to get help (features like fling, horizontal view paging, and so on).  What is the indicator of the view paging called?  How does one do it and with dynamic pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to go here and read.

[Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Also check out commonsware books on developement. This is the best way to get started.

Comment: This is the place everyone starts from. But it doesn't quite help to find what a feature is called. Also its not easy to understand for a beginner. Only thing that worked for me was terming it by myself and googling. Anyways, thanks for your help cfl22